# Is cross platform multiplayer possible?

Tags: borderlands-2

As Borderlands 2 has been released on multiple platforms, would it be possible for me to play Borderlands 2 on PC with a friend that is playing on a PlayStation 3 or Xbox 360 or is it only possible to play with people on the same platform?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer is NO, for now.

According to the Gearbox community manager:

> Cross-platform multiplayer is something we'd really like to support,
>   but is also something that historically been pretty tricky to
>   implement across all platforms. It's something we're continuing to
>   look into, both for Borderlands 2 and our works beyond, and hopefully
>   something we'll be able to do in the future.

[source](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?p=2599486&postcount=6)

Comment: While it would be possible for PS3 and PC users to play with one another, with the seperation of XBOX Live, I don't see it happening.

Comment: @Ramhound There's more history of PC and Xbox 360 cross-platform multiplayer than there is of PC and PS3. Windows PCs and Xbox 360 are both Microsoft platforms and I can at least name one title that supported this feature, Shadowrun.

Comment: @SionSheevok if you can only name 1 game that support cross-platform play between PC and 360, then it's exactly the same amount of history as there is for cross-platform play between PC and PS3 (Portal 2) - one game each.

Comment: Correct, but at this point, my comment is nearly a year old. The point was that Microsoft owns both platforms and there already existed a history of Microsoft supporting Xbox Live/Windows for Games Live. It's been done on both platforms now, but to think PC/PS3 is easier or more likely than PC/Xbox is questionable.

Comment: Source link is now broken. Anyone know of a mirror link?

Comment: Is this still true?