# Borderlands 2 co-op within same platform family?

Tags: xbox-360, borderlands-2, xbox-one

OK, I know cross-family platform play with Borderlands 2 (ex PS/XBox) is a no go, but will cross platform play within the same family (ex XBox 360/Xbox One) work?  I know you can transfer saves, but will they play together on a LAN?  I've got 2 360s not being used and my wife is getting annoyed with the split screen play on the XBox One.

Comment: You got 2 360s? Why not use those for co-op?

Comment: I can see where people would automatically say no, and ways that you might be able to get around this. This is also relevant to my interests, so I have actually contacted Microsoft for clarification.

Comment: @galacticninja - It's not a duplicate because I identified that it is a known fact that cross-family platforming is out (the other question brought up PCs and consoles).  This question is focusing specifically on cross-platform play within the same console family, i.e. PS3/PS4 or XBox 360/XBox One, not PC/PS, PS/XBox or PC/XBox.

Comment: @Chippies - My wife got the Handsome Collection for XBox One, so since we already have the one copy it wouldn't make sense to move back to the consoles we barely touch anymore.

Comment: The cross-family platforming you're thinking of is Windows/Linux/Mac, which are all run on a PC. There is no cross-platform there, since the hardware is pretty much the same in all cases, unlike different generations of consoles.

Comment: actually, @Chippies, PC and Mac are computer platforms. The operating systems are Linux, Windows and Mac OSX. Hardware changes a lot more then a console does. You can get many different variations of graphic cards, for example. There is usually software in the middle, and that's where the support comes from. For example, most games interface with DirectX, which then interfaces with the graphic cards. This is why many games are specific to Windows - Microsoft own DirectX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The verdict is in. If you are wanting to play via local area network, the answer is no. You can still play multiplayer.**

To directly quote the fine print, at the bottom of [the official Xbox page](http://www.xbox.com/) on [multiplayer](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/multiplayer);

> Multiplayer between Xbox 360 and Xbox One not supported.

This is why it took [the release of Xbox 360 emulation](http://www.theverge.com/2015/6/15/8785955/microsoft-xbox-one-xbox-360-emulator-software), to support Xbox 360 games on the Xbox One, rather then being able to support the older generation of games from release.

That said, you do have the option of Xbox emulation. With a 360 copy of Borderlands 2, you will still be able play together, online. There is one catch: It has not been released yet. Microsoft have promised "100 games this fall, and hundreds of games over the next months". Once they have released backwards compatibility support for this title, your in the clear.

Cross-platform play and the expected release cycle of games are advertised on the Xbox website, on the page detailing [Backwards Compatability](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/backward-compatibility).

I was unsure, myself, if this also meant local area network. I contacted Microsoft Support, directly, and asked them. Unfourtunetly, to quote ***"Vinz"*** at **Microsoft Support**:

> Yes, you need to access Live.

**TL,DR:** If you use a 360 copy of the game on Xbox One, you can still play with other 360 consoles online. Other then that, there are a few restrictions that prevent multiplayer between the two consoles.

Answer (score 0):

**No, Borderlands 2 doesn't support cross-platform co-op.**

Xbox 360 and Xbox One are different platforms (even though made by same company), so it falls into the cross-platform category.

Comment: Has that been stated anywhere by either Gearbox/2K or Microsoft where it specifically speaks of interoperability between both generations of the consoles?  If so, please link it.  All I've been able to find is blurbs about transferring saves from one console to the other, but nothing about LAN multiplayer.

Comment: The best I can give you is the excerpt from a deleted forum post by Gearbox on their own forum stating that cross-platform is not supported. It's in [this post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85105/63180). Xbox 360 and Xbox One being completely different platforms means that unless stated otherwise, there is no cross-platform support.

Comment: is this before or after the introduction of cross platform support? Ive just had microsoft confirm you can play if the xbox one is running a 360 version

Comment: Which I would agree with you there, except for the fact that cross platform save transfers within the same console family is supported.  So to what extent is the inter-family support?

Comment: I can't find any information on cross-platform compatibility, other than windows/linux/mac, which are all run on a PC, so it's hardly even cross-platform. Transferring save files is simple, as they just have to convert the file format. Having two completely different consoles be able to play co-op would require a very complex networking code.

Comment: @Timelord64 did they specifically mention if play between the 360 and One version was possible, or did they just imply that with their answer?

Comment: @Chaosbydesign he didnt need to. the xbox website directly advertises it. He confirmed that direct network isnt supported. You both have to go on live to play together.

Comment: http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/backward-compatibility to directly quote, "Play multiplayer with your friends no matter which console they’re on."

Comment: That implies playing the xbox360 version of the game on Xbox One, which is not what the question was.

Comment: @Chippies actually, OP directly asks if "cross platform between the two families" will work. OP mentions playing Borderlands 2 on xbox one, but does not directly ask about that version. We can assume that if OP is wishing to ALSO play on Xbox 360, they already intend to use at least one copy of the 360 version. Regardless, it appears this has answered all of OPs queries.

Comment: @Timelord64 OP mentions owning 2 360s, so if he wanted to play 360 with 360, he already had the means to do it (minus the games itself).

Comment: @Chippies it doesn't really matter what you interpret from the question. OP was happy with the solution, and he was the one that asked the question in the first place. I trust his interpretation over yours

Comment: @Timelord64 No need to get defensive over it. I'm just saying that backwards compatibility has nothing to do with being able to do cross-platform co-op. The whole question stems from the misunderstanding of what "cross-platform" is and why you can't play xbox one version of the game in co-op with xbox 360 version. Either way, your answer provides some evidence to the fact that there is no cross-platform support, so there's no need to argue about interpreting the question anymore.